# "TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable" when checking for element in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python 3.7, on Spyder, and have the following code

```
def NailingPlanks(A,B,C):
    numInervals = len(A)
    maxNails = len(C)
    
    intervals = []
    covered = [0]*numInervals
    
    for i in range(numInervals):
        interval = []
        for j in range(A[i],B[i]+1): interval.append(j)
        intervals.append(interval)
        
    nails = []
    nailUsed = [False] * maxNails
    print('covered = ', covered)
    while (0 in covered):
        MaxCovered = 0
        for i in range(maxNails):
            if not nailUsed[i]:
                nail = C[i]
                cnt = 0
                for j in range(numInervals):
                    if covered[j]==0 and nail in intervals[j]: cnt += 1
                if cnt>MaxCovered:
                    MaxCovered = cnt
                    maxIndex = i
        nails.append(maxIndex)
        nailUsed[maxIndex] = True
        for j in range(numInervals):
            if nail in intervals[j]: covered=1
            
    print('nails=', nails)
    return len(nails)
```

When it runs, I get the following output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-492-8fb88643c6e1>", line 1, in <module>
    NailingPlanks(A,B,C)

File "<ipython-input-491-4c2e538033de>", line 16, in NailingPlanks
while (0 in covered):

TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

I get the following in the terminal

```
not (0 in covered)
Out[494]: False
```

Comment: You are changing the list to an int `covered=1`. Did you want `covered[j]=1`?

Comment: That's it.  Thanks very much!

Comment: That's why a [mcve] is useful and even required here.